# play framework route not working if i send post http method via potman using content-type: application/json

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, postman

I'm sending value in body of `postman` which has `content-type: application/json` , but route is not able to call associated method, whenever i send something other `content-type` route method is working which obviously will give `error`.  it was working before committing my code,so i am unable to find here that why it is not working with `json` now.

my route is 
`POST/files->controllers.Application.fileCreateUsingJSON()`

and method is :

```
public static Result fileCreateUsingJSON() {

 FileDetail mFileDetail = null;
 String classContent = getString("classContent");
 String className = getString("className").toString().replace("\"", "");
 mFileDetail = FileHandler.fileWriter(className, classContent);
 if (mFileDetail == null) {
     Gson gson = new Gson();
    FileJSON mFileJSON = new FileJSON(false, -1, null, null, null, null);
    response().setContentType("application/json");
    return badRequest(gson.toJson(mFileJSON));
 } else {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    FileJSON mFileJSON = new FileJSON(true, mFileDetail.fileDetailId, mFileDetail.fileName,
            mFileDetail.createdDate, mFileDetail.filePath, mFileDetail.updateDate);
    response().setContentType("application/json");
    return ok(gson.toJson(mFileJSON));
  }
}
```

`getstring` method used to handle `json` is:

```
private static String getString(String paramName) {

ObjectMapper mapper;
JsonNode request = null;
mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    request = mapper.readValue(request().body().asJson().toString(), JsonNode.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is the method `fileCreateUsingJSON` called when you POST some JSON data? Do you see some errors / exceptions in log?